# Returning the right number of columns, but all rows are empty

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to do a simple Read from mysql using Gorm.

```
type Table struct {
    Id string `json:"Id" db:"Id" column:"Id" gorm:"column:Id"`
}


func getTable(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t:= []Table{}
    db.Debug().Table("Table").Find(&t)
    fmt.Println(table)
    fmt.Println("len(table)")
}
```

MySql has a `table` with column `id` as primary_key

The result im getting is a table with the correct size, but all rows are empty...

`....[{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}]`

But the total number of row count is correct `len(t) = 20523`

I think what I am doing wrong is in the definition of the `Table struct`, maybe I incorrectly specifying the name of the Id column? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Your `gorm` tag doesn't look right.  Does this help? http://gorm.io/docs/models.html

Comment: How does `Gorm` even know how to map `MySql` to my `Table struct`

Comment: I tried`Id string `json:"Id" db:"Id" column:"Id" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"`` and it was the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use db.Raw and check the field has the name "Id" like this:

```js
type Table struct {
 Id string `json:"Id" db:"Id" column:"Id" gorm:"column:Id"`
}

func getTable() {
 t := []Table{}
 db := config.ConnectDB()
 defer db.Close()

 db.Raw(" SELECT idEvaluacionAnual as Id FROM EvaluacionesAnuales ").Scan(&t)
 fmt.Println(t.Id)
 fmt.Println("len(table)")
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: My sir, I do not want to use Raw Sql with Gorm. I might as well not use `Gorm` at all in that case.

Comment: You said your Sql table has the field id, then you need to specify the name in the metadata of the variable in Gorm: gorm:"column:id" lowercase

Comment: Did you do it in lowercase?

Comment: My actual name of the column is `adId`  so I used gorm:"column:adId" which is in camelcase

Comment: `type Kijiji struct {
 adId string `json:"adId" db:"adId" gorm:"column:adId" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"`
}`

Comment: type Kijiji struct { **AdId** string json:"adId" db:"adId" gorm:"column:adId" gorm:"type:varchar(20)"` }` it must this like this

Comment: Thank you sir!! It worked!! Can you point to me where it says in Gorm that I must have capital? These small details is really bogging my development time down. I spent all day trying to figure it out before asking on SO.

Comment: @Telenoobies That's not specific to Gorm. It's basics of Go. Maybe you should spend some time learning the language you're using so you're not so "bogged down". https://tour.golang.org/basics/3

Comment: @Gavin Sorry, I do not see how that link is related to my problem. I am not trying to export a variable. There was no specification that says the member of a `struct` must have first letter capitalized.

Comment: @Telenoobies That link is only the 3rd page of the Tour of Go, I suggest going through the entire thing. Packages can export more than variables, including types, and properties of those types if they happen to be structs. The same information from the page I linked applies to exporting *anything* from a package.

Comment: But I'm not trying to export... I just want Gorm to populate my struct.